# How can i manage models when i have multiple languege website laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

in my Laravel project i have two tables. One for products and another one for translations of products.

```
1 - products
2 - product_translations
```

So i want to write my controller for adding a product and it translations.

How can i  manage it? should i write two models for my tables or is there another way with design patterns? (like if i can write an adapter to handle it)

And what is the best practice to handle the process of inserting in two tables (first, i have to insert row in `products` table and then i have to insert a row in my `product_translations` table.)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you familiar with laravel localization? [link↗️](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization)

Comment: @MahdiRashidi Yes but it has nothing to do with my question. I am talking about translation for texts in database, not site.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I guess i found the answer. [This](https://github.com/Astrotomic/laravel-translatable) package will do everything for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add multiple language, you can use localization.
But if you want to insert for two tables, is best to insert `product` after insert for `product_translation`!